# Our own Ruby Command line option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any command line option for doing some customized operation is ruby.

I want like this `ruby sample.rb -xxxx yes/no`

Where **xxxx**  stands for the option of my own

Note: yes/no will do some performance

Comment: Well, for starters, have a look at the standard library - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html. It provides the basics for you to write a mail script of your own.

Comment: In Rails there's [Action Mailer](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), you could invoke it from a [custom rake task](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks).

Comment: Guys please look into the edited question

Comment: Are you looking for http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/632/233/posted-docs.index.html? or http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/argv.htm?

Comment: Are you looking to modify the `ruby` executable such that no matter what `sample.rb` or other file you run, the option will change the behavior of `ruby`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wondering if you can pass parameters to ruby scripts?  Sure...

```
Mac:~/so[master]$ cat cli.rb
p ARGV
Mac:~/so[master]$ ruby cli.rb --isTheSkyBlue yes
["--isTheSkyBlue", "yes"]
Mac:~/so[master]$
```

Comment: Great. This solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby standard library includes [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) which will do what you need.